# CodeIgniter: Undefined property $db

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

In CodeIgniter 3.1.3 I extended CI_Model in application/core/MY_Model.php:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct($id = NULL) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load($id);
    }

    public function load($id) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->query($this->_table);
        if ($row = $query->result()) {
            // @todo Process results
        }
        // Free the resources.
        $query->free_result();
    }

}
```

My User_model looks like this:

```
class User_model extends MY_Model {

    public function __construct($id = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($id);
    }

}
```

I also extended the CI_Controller in application/core/MY_Controller as follows:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }
}
```

I autoloaded the database connection in application/config/autoload.php as:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Without loading the User_model in the controller I was able to run migrations, so the database connection is configured correctly. But when I added $this->load->model('User_model') I get the error "Undefined property: User_model::$db".

If I let User_model extend CI_Model it runs without errors and with a var_dump in the homepage's controller it shows that the database is autoloaded correctly. But as soon as I put MY_Model in between, the database class is undefined in the model and also $this->load in the model returns NULL, so it appears the model is not properly constructed.

I can only imagine this to be a very small mistake, but I've been staring at it for hours with several breaks in between and I just don't see it. Can anyone else help me?

Answer (score 1):

From a controller, lets say A_controller

```
$this->load->library('MyLib');
```

In MyLib, my original issue is this block

```
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->load->model('my_model');

    $this->active_model = $ci->my_model;
```

Then the miracle come when it become

```
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->load->model('my_model');
    $ci->my_model->db = & $ci->db;

    $this->basic_model = $ci->my_model;
```

When CI loads a model $db property come along with CI.
So, when you call $this->db in model which means you want "my_model" have the property, right?
What I did just link the property from CI to my_model!!!